# LinkedList Queue implementation

Tags: java, linked-list, queue

I'm working on a project which simulates (very simple/watered down) a network. The basis of this is to learn how to implement a `Queue`. I understand there are many ways to go about this, but I ultimately went with a `LinkedList` mainly because of it's nature (FIFO) which makes it easy to utilize in a `Queue`. I would appreciate any feedback on my implementation, and would also greatly appreciate with any critiques on my `Queue`'s `toString()`, I know it is an unconventional way of doing it but I thought it would by a nice chance to work on recursion.

The data class in the this project is the `Packet`. It represents a packet and code is as follows. I've omitted the getters and setters for brevity:

```
private static int packetCount;         // Determined at the time of the objects creation [incremental]
private int id;                         // Assigned by packetCount
private int packetSize;                 // Size of the packet being sent
private int timeArrive;                 // Creation "time stamp"
private int timeToDest;                 // Number of simulation units it took for the packet to arrive to destination

/**
 * Default constructor
 */
public Packet() {
    id = 0;
    packetSize = 0;
    timeArrive = 0;
    timeToDest = 0;

}

public Packet(int id, int packetSize, int timeArrive, int timeToDest) {
    this.id = id;
    this.packetSize = packetSize;
    this.timeArrive = timeArrive;
    this.timeToDest = timeToDest;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Packet #" + id + " => arrive at simulation unit: " + timeArrive + " => packet size: " + packetSize;
    }
}
```

Here is my `Node` class:

```
public class Node {
private Packet data;
private Node next;
private Node prev;

public Node() {
    next = null;
    data = null;
    prev = null;
}

public Node(Packet data) {
    this.data = data;
    next = null;
    prev = null;
}

public Packet getData() {
    return data;
}

public Node getNext() {
    return next;
}

public Node getPrev() {
    return prev;
}

public void setData(Packet data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public void setNext(Node next) {
    this.next = next;
}

public void setPrev(Node prev) {
    this.prev = prev;
}


}
```

And my `Queue` class which is actually a router within this simulation:

```
/**
 * Represents a router on the network [queue]
 */
public class Router{

private Node head;
private Node tail;
int size;

public Router() {
    head = null;
    tail = null;
    size = 0;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return head == null;
}

public int size() {
    return size;
}

public void enqueue(Packet packet) {
    Node node = new Node(packet);

    if(head == null) {
        head = node;
        tail = node;
    }
    tail.setNext(node);
    node.setPrev(tail);
    tail = node;

    size++;
}

public Packet dequeue(){
    if(isEmpty()) {
        try {
            throw new Exception("Underflow");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    Node ptr = head;
    head = ptr.getNext();

    if(head == null) {
        tail = null;
    }

    size--;

    return ptr.getData();
}

public Packet peek() {
    if(isEmpty()) {
        try {
            throw new Exception("Underflow");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return head.getData();
}

public String recToString(StringBuilder strBlder, Node cursor) {

    if(cursor !=head) {
        strBlder.append(cursor.getData().toString() + "\n");
        recToString(strBlder, cursor.getPrev());
    }

    strBlder.append(cursor.getData().toString());
    return strBlder.toString();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    return recToString(s, tail);
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you throw Exceptions, catch them immediately and ignore them? You should use/create appropriate types of Exceptions and let your methods throw them.

Answer (score 2):

**Packet**

```
private static int packetCount; // Determined at the time of the objects creation [incremental]
```

I would remove this field. *Personally* I feel it's odd for a Packet to need to know the number of packets. Apart from that you would need to synchronize access to this field, should your class ever be used in a multi-threading environment.

**Node**

- make `data` final. A node should never change it's data once created. Remove the setter as well.
- Remove the default constructor `public Node()`. It is unused and does not initialize the (now final) field `data`.
- rename the field `data` to `packet`. A clear naming will help other developers and your future self remember what is stored here.

**Router**

`size` should be private too

```
public void enqueue(Packet packet) {
    Node node = new Node(packet);

    if (head == null) {
        head = node;
        tail = node;
    }
    tail.setNext(node);
    node.setPrev(tail);
    tail = node;

    size++;
}
```

if `head == null`you set `head = tail = node`. You now have three references to the same Packet object. After that you set next and prev on this object to itself.

```
public Packet dequeue() {
    Node ptr = head;
    head = ptr.getNext();

    if (head == null) {
        tail = null;
    }

    size--;

    return ptr.getData();
}
```

If now `dequeue` is called, `head` is assigned to `ptr` (which is the Packet pointing forward and backward to itself. `head` is assigned `ptr.next` which means, it is still the same object. `head == null` will never be true. For every subsequent call to `dequeue` you will get that Packet.

If another Packet ist enqueued the next call to `dequeue` will return the first Packet once more and then return the new Packet, removing it from your list.

To fix that, change `enqueue` to

```
public void enqueue(Packet packet) {
    Node node = new Node(packet);

    if (head == null) {
        head = node;
        tail = node;
    } else {
        tail.setNext(node);
        node.setPrev(tail);
        tail = node;
    }

    size++;
}
```

Are you sure, that the output created by `recToString` is what you want/need?

Calling

```
router.enqueue(new Packet(11, 11, 11, 11));
router.enqueue(new Packet(22, 22, 22, 22));
router.enqueue(new Packet(33, 33, 33, 33));
System.out.println(router.toString());
```

yields the output:

```
Packet #33 => arrive at simulation unit: 33 => packet size: 33
Packet #22 => arrive at simulation unit: 22 => packet size: 22
Packet #11 => arrive at simulation unit: 11 => packet size: 11Packet #22 => arrive at simulation unit: 22 => packet size: 22Packet #33 => arrive at simulation unit: 33 => packet size: 33
```

Since you implement `FIFO` I think, the first (`head`) element should be printed first.

Remove `recToString` and replace `toString`:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    Node current = head;
    while (current != null) {
        result.append(current.getData().toString()).append("\n");

        current = current.getNext();
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

It now starts at `head` and walks forward through the list till it hits the end.

With `recToString` removed the only call to Node#getPrev() got removed, too. A FIFO-structure does not need to be double linked. Let's remove it.

**Node:**

```
public class Node {
    private Packet data;
    private Node next;

    public Node(Packet data) {
        this.data = data;
        next = null;
    }

    public Packet getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node next) {
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

**Router#enqueue()**

```
public void enqueue(Packet packet) {
    Node node = new Node(packet);

    if (head == null) {
        head = node;
        tail = node;
    } else {
        tail.setNext(node);
        tail = node;
    }

    size++;
}
```

**Edit:**
*Forgot my own comment.*

**Exception handling**

Create your own Exception:

```
public class QueueEmptyException extends RuntimeException {
    public QueueEmptyException() {
    }

    public QueueEmptyException(final String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public QueueEmptyException(final String message, final Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

    public QueueEmptyException(final Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }

    public QueueEmptyException(final String message, final Throwable cause, final boolean enableSuppression, final boolean writableStackTrace) {
        super(message, cause, enableSuppression, writableStackTrace);
    }
}
```

Create a method that throws the Exception, if the queue is empty:

```
private void assertNotEmpty() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw new QueueEmptyException("Queue is emtpy");
    }
}
```

Change `peek`

```
public Packet peek() {
    assertNotEmpty();

    return head.getData();
}
```

and `dequeue`

```
public Packet dequeue() {
    assertNotEmpty();

    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Since you handle data in FIFO order, I don't see the need for the `prev`. In any case if you use it, make sure that `dequeue` clears `head.prev` after node removal.
- As pointed by @Mpirious, catching your own exceptions doesn't make sense. What's worse, after detecting an empty queue the code keeps going.
- Getters and setters in `Node` do not serve any purpose: private members with unrestricted access are as good as public.